# How to boot via grub2 rescue promt on UEFI system?

Tags: boot, system-installation, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 by booting from a USB, choosing "Try Ubuntu without installing", and then inserting another USB and directing the installer to install there. I told the installer to instal the bootloader on `/dev/sdc2` which is the ESP. I know the bootloader was indeed installed because I can see the shim and GRUB EFI files on that partition now.

However, when I tried to boot after installing, instead of giving me the boot menu it only booted to the rescue prompt:

```
grub rescue>
```

I then found that my ESP partition is `hd0,gpt2` while I expected `hd1,gpt2` (using grub's naming scheme here).

I looked through similar questions but unfortunately I only found information about BIOS systems and not EFI, where `/` also contains `/boot(/efi)`. I am looking for a way how to proceed with `/` on `hd0,gtp3` and the grub efi files on the other disk. The kernel and initrd are both located inside of the ESP, the problem must be at another point.

How can I fix this?

Output of `ls`:

```
(hd0) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt8) (hd1,gpt7) (hd1,gpt6) (hd1,gpt5) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1)
```

output of `ls (hd0,gpt2)/`:

```
syslininux/ vmlinuz.efi inird.lz efi/
```

content of `/media/ubuntu/ba6e9aff-b9b7-4c4f-8441-98db8ec7a08a/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-ba6e9aff-b9b7-4c4f-8441-98db8ec7a08a' {
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd2,gpt3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd2,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,gpt3  ba6e9aff-b9b7-4c4f-8441-98db8ec7a08a
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ba6e9aff-b9b7-4c4f-8441-98db8ec7a08a
fi
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ba6e9aff-b9b7-4c4f-8441-98db8ec7a08a ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic  }
```

Update:
i reinstalled with `grub-install /dev/sdb2` grub into /dev/sdb2 but most grubfiles are still in /dev/sdb3 so grub can't access it because it don't know how to load the ext2.mod. Part of the output was using `x86_64-efi` arch.

I messed a bit with the rescue console and getting slowly better but I may have found the cause, why it can't access it. The grub rescue mode only acceptes only i386-pc modfiles, but all installed modfiles are x86_64-efi ones.

Comment: It was? I'm glad to hear it, but I suggested various things in chat. Could you please post an answer explaining what you did?

Comment: arrasndly not, I wrote this coment to soon, sure I will

Comment: it was a incomlete EFI implentation, that caused it. I could work around it see answer.

Answer (score 1):

All this simply because somebody didn't fully implement the UEFI specification.

All you have to do is boot a live system and:

```
sudo mount -U <UUID of your ESP> /mnt
sudo mkdir /mnt/EFI/BOOT
sudo cp -v /mnt/boot/<your-vendor>/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/BOOT/
```

and then shutdown, remove the live system and reboot.

More info about the path used can be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Booting_from_removable_media).